# Calling 32-bit DLL from 32-bit LabVIEW on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: dll, 32bit-64bit, labview

I am working in a 64-bit Windows 7 environment and running a 32-bit version of LabVIEW.
I need to link up a specific instrument to LabVIEW, using a LabVIEW library which was given to me by the company that made the instrument. The library includes calls to a couple 32-bit DLL files which were also given to me by the company.
LabVIEW is having trouble reading those DLL files, and whenever I try to open a file I get a popup message that says "Error loading DLL". Is this because of a 32-bit/64-bit incompatibility, or is it due to something else altogether ?

Thanks,

Comment: You must check the DLL in the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Comment: Thanks, Charles, I did exactly that and it found the error... There was an erroneous path buried somewhere which led to the error in the dll initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DLL in the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), there must be a DLL dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call at 32 bit DLL from 32 bit LabVIEW in a 64 bit OS. I believe the issue is something else.